# how to get regID using pushwoosh android native SDK

Tags: android, notifications, pushwoosh

I am using PushWoosh android native SDK for push notifications. I want to reuse the regId provided by GCM on successful registration. How can I get this regID using android native SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the regID from the GCM registration, store it in `SharedPreferences` to access it later.

To store it

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
String regId = gcm.register(ID);
SharedPreferences shp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PrefKey",
        getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
shp.edit().putString("RegId",regId).commit();
```

To get it

```
SharedPreferences shp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PrefKey",
        getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
if (shp != null && shp.contains("RegId"))
    regId = shp.getString("RegId", null);
```

Comment: The ID parameter in gcm.register(ID) requires array of String. What should exactly be the value of ID ?

Comment: You can pass in an array of Strings, but all you need to give it is your project ID in the Google API console (the number at the end of the URL. ex: https://console.developers.google.com/project/123456789012)